# What does the ":" colon do for indexing in this case?

Tags: python-3.x

I've never seen a colon used in this way in python and need an explanation.
Here `dim`, `in_features`, and `out_features` are all int.  `i` is the index counter in a for loop.  When I use `dim:(i + 1)` on it's own it doesn't throw an error, but also doesn't do anything.  If I use `0:(i+1)` on it's own i get a `SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation`.
A reproducible snippet is below.

```
dim = 8
in_features = dim
hidden_dim = 3
out_features = dim * hidden_dim
weight = np.zeros([out_features, in_features])
for i in range(dim):
    weight[i * out_features // dim:(i + 1) * out_features // dim,\
           0:(i + 1) * in_features // dim] \
           = np.random.uniform(size=[out_features // dim, (i + 1) * in_features // dim])
```

Comment: I think this is just `weight[ a : b : c]` where `a,b,c` are rather complicated expressions. A reproducible example would help. The comma rather than the colon is what seems mysterious. That makes `b` a tuple, which doesn't make sense in a slice.

Comment: ok sheesh -- i think maybe i'm just so used to languages like R that have a different order/priority of operations then.  Parenthesis would make this more clear i guess!  At the very least I think we agree this is confusing notation even if it is allowed syntactically..

Comment: With the code, this seems like [numpy array slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) with the comma delimiting the dimensions. Thus it parses as `weight[a:b , 0:c]`